# Custom DateTime validation in ASP .NET - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, datetime, asp.net-mvc-3

I try to implement new validationrules in my MVC-Project but i wont become a validation-errormsg in my view.
What is wrong with the code? I have googlet alot and thought i have done all right -.-

WebConfig:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> 
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> 
</appSettings>
```

Model:

```
public class Model1 : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{d:0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
    public DateTime Wunschtermin { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (Wunschtermin < DateTime.Now) yield return new ValidationResult("error1!", new[] { "Wunschtermin" });
        if (Wunschtermin.Date > DateTime.Today.AddYears(2)) yield return new ValidationResult("error2", new[] { "Wunschtermin" });
    }
    ...
```

View:

```
@model TestMvcApplication.Models.Model1

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
    ...
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Wunschtermin)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Wunschtermin)
        </div>
    ...
```

Edit:

Maybe I can override the RangeAttribute and avoid the problem:

```
[Range (DateTime.Now, DateTime.Today.AddYears(2))]
```

usefull?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have solved it myself, the code in the Controler was wrong:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
```

with a smal change:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Model1 collection)
```

it works well :-)